# Power series of exponential : A proof .

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, power-series, exponential-function, solution-verification

Hi I'm working on power series to begin let prove that :

My claim

> > Let $x$ a real number then we have :
> > $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

### Proof

We want to find the coefficient such that :

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$$

Or :

$$y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\ln(y)^k$$

We differentiate to get :

$$1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{na_n\ln(y)^{n-1}}{y}\quad (1)$$

But :

$$1=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_k\ln(y)^k}{y}\quad (2)$$

With $(1)$ and $(2)$ and after simplification we get :
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\ln(y)^k=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_n\ln(y)^{n-1}$$

Or :
$$0=a_1-a_0+\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}((r+1)a_{r+1}-a_r)\ln(y)^r$$

Now we put $(r+1)a_{r+1}-a_r=0$ and $a_1=a_0$ and now we have the coefficient .

With my proof we work with sequences , first derivative , inverse function .I take care about the notation and if there is a problem it's here I think .

### Question :

Is it fine ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Hi, what is your definition of $\exp$ and/or $\ln$ ?

Comment: "Derivate" is NOT a verb.  Differentiate is a verb.

Comment: What, precisely, are you attempting to prove, and what assumptions are you starting with?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch as definition I start with the differential equation $f'=f$

Comment: @kimchilover see my edits

Comment: @c-love-garlic Try taking the derivative of $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$ term-by term and see what you can conclude about the $a_n$.

Comment: I see.  A proper proof would state  the definition of $\exp$ that you are using and not force one to look at the comments, and would specify if you were interested in a formal power series, or a convergent power series,  or what.  While we are at it, is $x$ a real number, a complex number, an infinite matrix, or what?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Oh I see now thanks .

Comment: @c You are welcome .